# What is required for the return of an operation Contract?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Does it have to be serializable, or what not?

It seems that when i use a custom class, i would do something like:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    IECInstance testme();
```

and in the definition of it:

```
public IECInstance testme()
    {
        IECInstance tst = ...;
        return tst;
    }
```

I was thinking that there was something required such that this sort of thing would return.  RIght now it returns a 504, timeout error.

Possibly, this item isnt  serializable, and that was the big thing i was thinking was the issue.

The interface for the **IECInstance** is:

```
public interface IECInstance : 
    IECNamedValueContainer, 
    IECValueContainer, 
    IEnumerable<IECPropertyValue>, 
    IEnumerable, 
    IECDump, 
    ICloneable, 
    IExtendable
    {
    ...
    }
```

and i was thinking that at least one if not more of those items were serialized, but the interface itself is *not* labeled at the top with:  **[Serialized]** or **[Serializable]**

What is required for the return type?

Comment: You need to apply Serializable attribute to your return type. Don't forget that Serializable attribute is not inheritable so if you apply it to interface then it won't work. You need to apply it directly to class.

Comment: What if the object is not allowed to be changed, it is from a DLL?

Comment: Also, if you haven't already make sure you have added [ServiceContract] above your interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `ServiceKnownTypeAttribute`

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(WhateverYourECInstanceTypeIs))]
IECInstance testme();
```

and yeah the concrete type will need to be serializeable like so

```
[DataContract]
public class WhateverYourECInstanceTypeIs : IECInstance 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so i am guessing that outside the base data types, i would have to use data contracts to pass data about, as that will help define more or less, a JSON object of sorts?

Comment: Yes. Before DataContract, in the ASMX times, you would of used that serializeable attribute. Now, any class that is a DataContract, with DataMembers can be serialized to json/xml via DataContractSerializer or DataContractJsonSerializer. Ofcourse you can serialize using them directly, however in WCF you would be using endpoints behaviors which leverage the appropriate serializer. It looks like you are trying to do a JSON web service, maybe REST? If you can consider WebAPI.

Comment: We were doing fairly simple RESTful services, which we can move to WebAPI.  The issue it seems is that the IECInstance is an interface mostly, but the structure itself is serializable, so im working to make a structure such that either WebAPI OR RESTful would make use of.